# Python multiple inheritance: How to inherit from two parents?

Tags: python, inheritance

I am trying to understand multiple inheritance. In my code, I have two parent classes, four children classes and one grandchild class, which inherits from some of the children.

Here is my code:

```
class ParentA:
    def __init__(self, time_span):
        print('Parent A start')
        self.time_span = time_span
        self.nameA = 'Parent A'
        print('Parent A end')


class ParentB:
    def __init__(self, time_span):
        print('Parent B start')
        self.time_span = time_span
        self.nameB = 'Parent B'
        print('Parent B end')


class Child1(ParentA, ParentB):
    def __init__(self, time_span):
        print('Child1 before init')
        super().__init__(time_span)
        print('Child1 start')
        self.name_child1 = 'Child 1'
        print('Child1 end')


class Child2(ParentA, ParentB):
    def __init__(self, time_span):
        print('Child2 before init')
        super().__init__(time_span)
        print('Child2 start')
        self.name_child2 = 'Child 2'
        print('Child2 end')


class Child3(ParentA, ParentB):
    def __init__(self, time_span):
        print('Child3 before init')
        super().__init__(time_span)
        print('Child3 start')
        self.name_child3 = 'Child 3'
        print('Child3 end')


class Child4(ParentA):
    def __init__(self, time_span):
        print('Child4 before init')
        super().__init__(time_span)
        self.time = time_span
        print('Child 4, time: ', self.time)


class Grandchild(Child2, Child3, Child4):
    def __init__(self, time_span):
        print('Grandchild before init')
        super().__init__(time_span)
        self.name_grandchild = 'Grandchild'
        print('Grandchild end')


def main():
    par_a = ParentA(24)
    c1 = Child1(24)
    c2 = Child2(24)
    c3 = Child3(24)
    c4 = Child4(24)
    gc = Grandchild(24)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output from running the code is:

```
Parent A start
Parent A end
Child1 before init
Parent A start
Parent A end
Child1 start
Child1 end
Child2 before init
Parent A start
Parent A end
Child2 start
Child2 end
Child3 before init
Parent A start
Parent A end
Child3 start
Child3 end
Child4 before init
Parent A start
Parent A end
Child 4, time:  24
Grandchild before init
Child2 before init
Child3 before init
Child4 before init
Parent A start
Parent A end
Child 4, time:  24
Child3 start
Child3 end
Child2 start
Child2 end
Grandchild end
```

In my setup, no children or grandchildren inherits from ParentB. I want to access nameB from any of the children/grandchild. How can I accomplish this?

I have looked at other examples, e.g. this one: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/super-multiple-inheritance-diamond-problem (example under 'Multiple inheritance, super, and the Diamond Problem), but in this case, there is only one parent on the top level.

Comment: I am not sure what do you want exactly. may be this reference helps you https://github.com/chavarera/PythonScript/blob/master/Class/multipleinheritance.md

Comment: It works if I do like in the link. But: I thought that this approach was the 'old' approach, and that super() now replaces this? Obviously not?

Comment: What I want is to code a hydrological model. ParentA corresponds to geographical area of model and all parameters/functions related to that. Directly under ParentA / area are child classes corresponding to different modules of the model (Snow, GroundWater, Soil etc). ParentB corresponds to initial conditions of the model. I therefore want all the children / modules of model to inherit both initial conditions for running the model and specs of area. The grandchild corresponds to adjustment of the model output, which needs access to more than one child (module) to do the modelcalculations again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like multiple inheritance is what you need, though it is unclear if the code you provided is the actual code in your program, or if it is a truncated version only meant to portray the structure of the code.

Based on this

> In my setup, no children or grandchildren inherits from ParentB. 
>   I want to access nameB from any of the children/grandchild.

..it sounds like you want to have only 1 variable in the whole program called 'nameB', and you want this variable to be accessible to all of the other objects. Please correct me if this is not accurate.
If this is the case, then you can either instantiate 'par_b' in `def main()` just as you are 'par_a', or try creating a static class for ParentB. The name of the 'B' object is then "ParentB" (instead of the 'par_b' nomenclature you would get by instantiating like you are in function main() ). Either way, 'B's attributes would be accessed via dot notation:

```
ParentB.nameB
```

or 
`par_b.nameB`

Back to the inheritance bit - if all of the child classes in your program inherit from ParentA and ParentB, and you instantiate each of the child classes once (as you do in function main()):

```
def main():
    par_a = ParentA(24)
    c1 = Child1(24)  
    c2 = Child2(24)
    c3 = Child3(24)
    c4 = Child4(24)
    gc = Grandchild(24)
```

then you have created 5 *different* variables in your program called "nameB", each belonging to different objects.
This means if you were to change ParentB.nameB, each of the child objects would still have their own attribute called "nameB" which would *not* change along with ParentB.nameB .


Further, if this code is the actual code for your program, then consider just creating a single class for whatever object you're trying to portray, and instantiate all of the objects in main as that same class type, since all of the classes appear to be near identical:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, time_span, name):
        print(name, " start")
        self.time_span=time_span
        self.name=name
        print(self.name, " end")


par_a = Thing(24, "ParentA")
c1 = Thing(24, "Child1")
c2 = Thing(24, "Child2")
c3 = Thing(24, "Child3")
c4 = Thing(24, "Child4")
gc = Thing(24, "Grandchild")
```

Because these objects "par_a", "c1", etc are *public* by default, then you can access them from anywhere in your program.
e.g.

```
print(par_a.name)
```

Sorry if I'm not understanding you correctly. Hope this helps.

*Editing to add code example based on new context in comments below.

```py
#the new top level class
class Model:
    def __init__(self, geo_area):
        self.geo_area=geo_area

        #do the typical model data initialization here
        self.init_data=None
        self.avg_day_temp=self.geo_area.avg_day_temp
        self.avg_night_temp=self.geo_area.avg_night_temp
        self.module1=self.geo_area.module1        
        self.module2=self.geo_area.module2        
        self.module3=self.geo_area.module3        
        self.module4=self.geo_area.module4        
        #if there are a lot more than 4 total modules, there are definitely more organized ways of handling the initialization. Probably keep a list of the required modules in GeoAreaHawaii.

        #create a new output modifier object (what was previously the grandchild class)
        self.out_mod=OutputModifier(self.module1, self.module2, self.module3, self.module4)

    def calcOutput(self):
        print(out_mod.processData("This is a test"))


#this was the "grandchild" class, no longer part of the inheritance tree
class OutputModifier:
    def __init__(self, module1=None, module2=None, module3=None, module4=None):
        self.module1=module1
        self.module2=module2
        self.module3=module3
        self.module4=module4

    def processData(self, data):
        #process the data thru the appropriate self.module methods
        processed_data=data
        return processed_data

#this was child1
class GroundWater:
    def __init__(self):
        #init GroundWater module
        pass
    def thingsThatGroundWaterDoes():
        pass

static class GeoAreaHawaii:
    #all the details on geo_area Hawaii 


#run it
geo_model_hawaii = Model(GeoAreaHawaii)
geo_model_hawaii.calcOutput()
```

Comment: What I want is to code a hydrological model. ParentA corresponds to geographical area of model and all parameters/functions related to that. Directly under ParentA / area are child classes corresponding to different modules of the model (Snow, GroundWater, Soil etc). ParentB corresponds to initial conditions of the model. I therefore want all the children / modules of model to inherit both initial conditions for running the model and specs of area. The grandchild corresponds to adjustment of the model output, which needs access to more than one child (module) to do the modelcalculations again.

Comment: The code I provided is therefore just the really basic structure of my real code. I am sorry for the confusion.. I want to access different functions under Child1, Child2, Child3 (modules of the model) in a particular function in Grandchild (the adjustment class). I am more than happy for other suggestions for structuring my code.

Comment: Wait, how can I make objects par_a, c1, c2 etc public in my code, accessible from anywhere? This may solve my problems, as I have no problems when I run the code for the actual model (involving both parents and children, but no grandchild). The problem arises when I want to access child functions from the grandchild. Where exactly do I create the objects? On top of my main script? Where?

Comment: Ok, sorry for the assumption on my part. Let me know if this is off the mark:
1. sounds like "Model" could be the top level class in your code, and Model would include the initialization data and attributes, unless this data varies per location?
2. then ParentA would be instantiated per geographical area, and ParentA would then inherit only from Model
3. based on whatever factors, ParentA would then instantiate the modules it needs (or if its only 3 or 4 of them, just include them all, always?)
4. Grandchild should not inherit, rather could be instantiated by ParentA, or be static

Comment: Sorry, i keep missing your comments as you write them. Re: making objects public, all objects are public by default. par_a, c1, c2, are public objects as soon as you define them. You would access them in logic by their name, or variable. 

If "Model" is the top level class, maybe you can instantiate Model with args 'geo_area' and 'modules'.

If you can give me an example of an input that drives the program, I can give you a better code example. e.g. do you manually run the program every time you want to create a new geo-area model instance?

Comment: I will set up hydrological models for different geographical areas. Input is precipitation and temperature, and output is runoff. The model for a specific area consists of a lot of parameters. Some parameters are fixed (don’t change with different weather conditions), e.g. altitude range / topography or percentage of glacier in the area. Some parameters are also fixed for a specific geographical area, but these I don’t know before I calibrate the model and thus get the assumed correct values (e.g. threshold temperature for snow melt). The rest of the params change from time step to time step

Comment: (e.g. the storage of water in different types of surface (soil, groundwater etc). All parameters are thus the same for all geographical areas, but contain different values. I need to set up the model, both to calibrate it and to run it on a daily basis.

Comment: It is a good idea to have a top class Model, with one subclass GeoArea and other subclasses Snow, Soil, ... (where the hydro equations are calculated). Is this what you mean? The thing is that I also need to use different initial conditions, depending on what 'mode' of the model I want to do (calibration or regular forecast run). For calibration, I want to do this for an historical period, thus different initial conditions than if I want to calculate tomorrows forecast. That's why I thought I could make a separate class InitCondition (ParentB).

Comment: Added a code example above. Actually doesn't use any inheritance, but you can still inherit from Model to GeoArea, or however you proceed.

In the code above, Model manages all other objects. Note how I instantiated OutputModifier (previously the grandchild class) *inside* the Model constructor, and passed the modules to it. Now when Model asks the instance of OutputModifier to perform an output calculation, the OutputModifier instance has access to the modules for calling the various methods and attributes it needs.